# How to fix "Can't write image data to path" Laravel 6.X

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I have created a Media class to upload images to store inside Storage public path of Laravel, but Intervention save method is not working

I have tried to change permission of directories but nothing. I have also tried to use public_path() function for my paths, or getRealPath() to the file.
I have also checked so many other similar questions related to this problem, and at the end i think it is probably a problem with Laravel v.6

This is the function to upload files:

```
/**
 * @param $entity
 * @param $file
 * @return string
 */
public function processFile($entity, $file)
{
    if (!$file->isValid()) {
        return false;
    }
    $imgName = preg_replace('@[a-z0-9]i@', '_', md5(uniqid(time())) . time());
    $fileName = $imgName . '.' . $file->extension();

    $pathSmall = "image/$entity/small/";
    $pathLarge = "image/$entity/large/";


    if (!Storage::exists($pathSmall)) {
        Storage::makeDirectory($pathSmall, 7777, true, true);
    }
    if (!Storage::exists($pathLarge)) {
        Storage::makeDirectory($pathLarge, 7777, true, true);
    }

    Image::make($file)->resize(310, 170)->save($pathSmall.$fileName);
    Image::make($file)->resize(1920, 1080)->save($pathLarge.$fileName);

    return $fileName;
}
```

I have tried to debug all the code and the problem is saving method, the image is making and resizing correctly but save is not working:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path (image/post/small/c2839f74e99f1c7f7c798171cf8ecf7b1571167248.jpeg) in file /home/vagrant/code/api-blog/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php on line 150
```

Comment: How have you changed the permissions?

Comment: whit bash comand and with ui of windows or mac, i have tried with both in local

Comment: Have you changed the permissions recursive? I‘ve had the exception multiple times and in every case wrong permissions caused the exception. On which line in your controller does the exception fire?

Comment: yes i have, the exeption fire in the class above, not in the controller,